# How to import import org.neuroph.core.*

Tags: java, libraries

In the process of learning artificial intelligence concepts, I came across this project in http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/tutorials/LensesClassification/LensesClassificationUsingNeuralNetworks.html . Source code provided by website includes libraries to be importedsuch as `import org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork;
import org.neuroph.core.learning.DataSet;
import org.neuroph.core.learning.DataSetRow;`

when i tried to implement that code in net beans, it didn't recognize those libraries, So can some one let me know how to import third party libraries like above, I am new to java and to stack overflow, pardon me if i am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: right click on your project and go through `buildpath`(some like that) menu then locate jars files you want to add

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the .jar archive for the library is added to the classpath.

[Here's Netbeans' reference on the subject.](http://oopbook.com/java-classpath-2/classpath-in-netbeans/)

After you have added it, your import statements should work.